# Equivalence operators(==) within function parameters

Tags: c, function, parameters

Whats the meaning of equivalence operators(==) within function parameters in c language like the following instruction?

binder_transaction(proc, thread, &tr, cmd == BC_REPLY);

Comment: I want to know about "==" in function arguments not in return value!

Comment: *Operators* in C language are used in *expressions*. That's all. There's absolutely no difference between expression used as a function argument or an expression used anywhere else (e.g. in return value). Regardless of the context, it is just an expression. Your attempt to establish a distinction between "function arguments" and "return value" is completely baseless. There's no distinction.

Comment: @Cert: The answer is given by the fact that it's a duplicate: there is no difference in where you apply the `==` operator, so the point that it passed as an argument is irrelevant. All you need to know is what `==` returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmd == BC_REPLY` as an argument of function `binder_transaction` is basically a `int` value passed to the function. This is equivalent to<sup>1</sup>

```
int b = (cmd == BC_REPL);              // Will return either 0 or 1
binder_transaction(proc, thread, &tr, b);
```

Comment: if(cmd == BC_REPLY)
   binder_transaction(proc, thread, &tr, True);
if(cmd != BC_REPLY)
   binder_transaction(proc, thread, &tr, False);
??

Comment: Yes, this double check version is equivalent, but much more verbose.

Comment: Comparison operators in C language do not produce `bool` values. The result of `==` in C is always an `int`.

Comment: @AnT; Yes, it is. Thanks.